# How detect a variable changed without using

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, embedded-linux

I have a big project and I realized that there is a variable that is changed without writing any value directly in it. I mean, I think that there is a pointer changing this value... I want to know if there is any software to detect this kind of faults.

I am using Valgrind but it does not give enough information to fix it.

Any help would be very appreciate.

Comment: you can use the debug mode "data" debug. You introduce a pointer to the variable and the program stops when that variable updates. Let me know if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Try printing the address of it.

Comment: Do you have custom memory manager in your code? or its direct malloc/free?

Comment: It'is direct malloc/free. The problem is that there are a lot of pointers and the project was started by another guy, so It is not easy to find the pointer to me.

Comment: Does [the explantion provided here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/eclipse_documentation/eclipse_c_c++_guide/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/eclipse_c_c++_guide_cdt_t_add_watch.htm) doesn't work?

Comment: I will try with the watchdog! I do not know if I will help me because I have 5 threads but I will try!

Answer (score 0):

In embedded systems, there are several methods to be notified when a variable changes:

1. Poll -- have some background code that monitors the variable and
   executes an associated function (via pointer) when the variable
   changes.
2. RTOS Mechanism -- Associate the variable with a semaphore, mutex or
   message queue.
3. Interrupt -- Maybe your variable is an interrupt register of some
   hardware device or you will get interrupted when a hardware
   registers is modified.

For polling, your best solution is to assign a pointer to the memory address and set the pointer to point to a `volatile` item.  You may want to use a *sleep* function call so as not to hog all the processor time.

Answer (score -1):

Visual C++ IDE can be used in debug mode to check the value of Variables. Any change in the variable will be dynamically updated in debug mode.

Comment: I am using eclipse and I am programming an embedded system that runs in linux.

Comment: How Visual C++ IDE will help to debug in Linux??

Comment: I tried to do something similar in GDB/GCC years ago, and never found a way to do this.  Just one more thing where Windows is ahead of Linux :-)

Comment: @osgx I have said debugging in Visual C++ IDE, since the question was not precise of the OS used (Windows/Linux/MacOS). Also, Visual C++ IDEs for Linux and Mac OS are also present. Please check out [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-can-i-install-visual-studio)

Comment: @JulenUranga Please refer to my previous comment to debug using visual c++ in linux. Alternatively, you can use Eclipse IDE as well to debug in Linux. Please follow this [link](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_debug_prog.htm)